# Angular on each load page with routing get data on "load"

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm struggling with fact that when on starting page with angularjs I can't get for example image dimensions, as we know it get be done on $(window).load when image exist. So in this case I can use `angular.element(window).load(function () {` but still on "back button" function inside won't be triggered

Here's my code

```
         'use strict';
        
        /* App Module */
        
        var myApp = angular.module('myAplication', [
            'ngRoute',
            'portfolioAnimations',
            'portfolioControllers',
            'portfolioServices'
        ]);
        
        myApp .config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
            function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
                $routeProvider.when('/', {
                    title: 'Home Page',
                    templateUrl: 'partials/portfolio-view.html',
                    controller: 'PortfolioList'
                }).when('/portfolio/:portfolioWorks', {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/portfolio-work-view.html',
                    controller: 'PortfolioWorkView'
                }).otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
        
            }]);
    
    /* Controllers */
    
    var portfolioControllers = angular.module('portfolioControllers', []);
    
    portfolioControllers.controller('PortfolioList', ['$scope', 'Work', 'scrollFunction',
        function ($scope, Work, scrollFunction) {
            $scope.worksList = Work.query();
            $scope.orderProp = 'age';
    
            angular.element(window).load(function () {
                console.log($(".img img").width())
            });
        }]
    );
    
    portfolioControllers.controller('PortfolioWorkView', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Work',
        function ($scope, $routeParams, Work) {
            $scope.work = Work.get({portfolioWorks: $routeParams.portfolioWorks}, function (work) {
                $scope.mainImageUrl = work.images[0];
            });
        }]);


/* Services */

var portfolioServices = angular.module('portfolioServices', ['ngResource']);

portfolioServices.factory('Work', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('portfolio/:portfolioWorks.json', {}, {
            query: {method: 'GET', params: {portfolioWorks: 'portfolioWorks'}, isArray: true}
        });
    }]);
```

So in this case on first load I get portfolio-view when image is and on load I can get it's dimensions, BUT when you route to another view and then press button I can't find way to get dimensions as page is already loaded, but going through internet couldn't find any solution for getting function trigger on load assets on specific view in controller.

My example in plunker: [EXAMPLE](https://plnkr.co/edit/e1b7AdfJyWVd264giCoT?p=preview) - unfortunatelly here I can't even reproduce getting image dimension on window load as it is in plunker

If something isn't clear please ask, I appreaciate any help

Comment: You could use ng-cookies or LocalStorageModule to set/Get the image dimension Or $broadcast

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully my research will help people around here

First of all we need to get array json as finished not as promise

```
   $scope.worksList.$promise.then(function (result) {
        $scope.worksList = result; // we have now full array so we can use it for  example to get value from object for example
        console.log($scope.workList[0].name) //will return 'work-one'

        //now with ngRoute code is not append yet so I just did (I'm not sure if its proper way but it is working)

        setTimeout(function () { //it takes only 1ms to append elements (tested with throating 250kb/s) so it works with weak user connection
           console.log($(".img").width() // and now we can have dimensions of elements created dynamically
        }, 1);
    });
```

**EDIT:** Also depends of animation of views using for example ng-animate, thats the timeout (in example 1 ms) , so if you have duration of animation lasts 300ms timeout will take 300ms

I'm aware that this might not be perfect solution but it is the cleaniest I could find so far :)
Happy coding guys